# Find the value of $\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\dots}}}$

Tags: nested-radicals

Evaluate

$$\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\dots}}}$$

I need some help with this question because I have no idea what is going on and help would be greatly appreciate :)

Comment: Your question translates to solving the equation _$\mathbf{x^2 = 6x}$_

Comment: You probably mean $6+x$.

Comment: @HSN yes, sorry

Comment: of interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical#Infinitely_nested_radicals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put
$$
x=\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\dots}}}
$$
squaring you get
$$
x^2=6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\dots}}}=6+x\;\;\;.
$$
Thus you simply have to solve
$$
x^2-x-6=0\;\;
$$
which has two solutions: $x=-2$ and $x=3$. But $x$ is clearly positive, thus you can conclude that
$$
\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\dots}}}=3\;.
$$

Comment: Why is X clearly positive?

Comment: Because you're considering a limit roots, which are necessarely non negative.

Answer (score 9):

$\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\dots}}} = \lim x_n$ where $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{6+x_n}$ and $x_0 \ge 0$.

As others have explained, *if this sequence converges*, then it converges to $3$.

To prove that it does converge, prove this:

- If $x_0 < 3 $ then the sequence is increasing and bounded above by $3$.
- If $x_0 > 3 $ then the sequence is decreasing and bounded below by $3$.

In both cases, you get a monotone bounded sequence, and so it converges.

Comment: Isn't it worth mentioning that $x_0=\sqrt{6}$? (+1), by the way.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva, this works regardless of $x_0$. It is natural to take $x_0=0$ but who knows what lies at the end of those ellipsis in $\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\dots}}}$ ? :-)

Comment: I know. :-) I meant in this case, to mention that the sequence in the OP is in fact increasing. Indeed $0$ and $\sqrt{6}$ lead to the same thing.

But yeah, I guess that's unimportant, my bad :D